# Code too slow when selecting optimal piecewise regression fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I'm making a program which fits a piecewise linear regression with up to 4-5 breakpoints in the data, and then deciding how many breakpoints is best to prevent over and underfitting. However, my code is *extremely* slow to run, due to how ungraceful it is.

A rough draft I have of my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, differential_evolution
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings


def segmentedRegression_two(xData,yData):

    def func(xVals,break1,break2,slope1,offset1,slope_mid,offset_mid,slope2,offset2):
            returnArray=[]
            for x in xVals:
                if x < break1:
                    returnArray.append(slope1 * x + offset1)
                elif (np.logical_and(x >= break1,x<break2)):
                    returnArray.append(slope_mid * x + offset_mid)
                else:
                    returnArray.append(slope2 * x + offset2)

            return returnArray

    def sumSquaredError(parametersTuple): #Definition of an error function to minimize
        model_y=func(xData,*parametersTuple)
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # Ignore warnings by genetic algorithm

        return np.sum((yData-model_y)**2.0)

    def generate_genetic_Parameters():
            initial_parameters=[]
            x_max=np.max(xData)
            x_min=np.min(xData)
            y_max=np.max(yData)
            y_min=np.min(yData)
            slope=10*(y_max-y_min)/(x_max-x_min)

            initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min]) #Bounds for model break point
            initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min])
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-y_max,y_min]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-y_max,y_min]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope])
            initial_parameters.append([y_max,y_min]) 



            result=differential_evolution(sumSquaredError,initial_parameters,seed=3)

            return result.x

    geneticParameters = generate_genetic_Parameters() #Generates genetic parameters



    fittedParameters, pcov= curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters) #Fits the data 
    print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)





    model=func(xData,*fittedParameters)

    absError = model - yData

    SE = np.square(absError) 
    MSE = np.mean(SE) 
    RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) 
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(yData))




    return Rsquared

def segmentedRegression_three(xData,yData):

    def func(xVals,break1,break2,break3,slope1,offset1,slope2,offset2,slope3,offset3,slope4,offset4):
            returnArray=[]
            for x in xVals:
                if x < break1:
                    returnArray.append(slope1 * x + offset1)
                elif (np.logical_and(x >= break1,x<break2)):
                    returnArray.append(slope2 * x + offset2)
                elif (np.logical_and(x >= break2,x<break3)):
                    returnArray.append(slope3 * x + offset3)
                else:
                    returnArray.append(slope4 * x + offset4)

            return returnArray

    def sumSquaredError(parametersTuple): #Definition of an error function to minimize
        model_y=func(xData,*parametersTuple)
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # Ignore warnings by genetic algorithm

        return np.sum((yData-model_y)**2.0)

    def generate_genetic_Parameters():
            initial_parameters=[]
            x_max=np.max(xData)
            x_min=np.min(xData)
            y_max=np.max(yData)
            y_min=np.min(yData)
            slope=10*(y_max-y_min)/(x_max-x_min)

            initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min]) #Bounds for model break point
            initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min])
            initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min])
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-y_max,y_min]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-y_max,y_min]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope])
            initial_parameters.append([y_max,y_min]) 
            initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope])
            initial_parameters.append([y_max,y_min]) 



            result=differential_evolution(sumSquaredError,initial_parameters,seed=3)

            return result.x

    geneticParameters = generate_genetic_Parameters() #Generates genetic parameters



    fittedParameters, pcov= curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters) #Fits the data 
    print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)





    model=func(xData,*fittedParameters)

    absError = model - yData

    SE = np.square(absError) 
    MSE = np.mean(SE) 
    RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) 
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(yData))


    return Rsquared

def segmentedRegression_four(xData,yData):

def func(xVals,break1,break2,break3,break4,slope1,offset1,slope2,offset2,slope3,offset3,slope4,offset4,slope5,offset5):
        returnArray=[]
        for x in xVals:
            if x < break1:
                returnArray.append(slope1 * x + offset1)
            elif (np.logical_and(x >= break1,x<break2)):
                returnArray.append(slope2 * x + offset2)
            elif (np.logical_and(x >= break2,x<break3)):
                returnArray.append(slope3 * x + offset3)
            elif (np.logical_and(x >= break3,x<break4)):
                returnArray.append(slope4 * x + offset4)
            else:
                returnArray.append(slope5 * x + offset5)

        return returnArray

def sumSquaredError(parametersTuple): #Definition of an error function to minimize
    model_y=func(xData,*parametersTuple)
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # Ignore warnings by genetic algorithm

    return np.sum((yData-model_y)**2.0)

def generate_genetic_Parameters():
        initial_parameters=[]
        x_max=np.max(xData)
        x_min=np.min(xData)
        y_max=np.max(yData)
        y_min=np.min(yData)
        slope=10*(y_max-y_min)/(x_max-x_min)

        initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min]) #Bounds for model break point
        initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min])
        initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min])
        initial_parameters.append([x_max,x_min])
        initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope]) 
        initial_parameters.append([-y_max,y_min]) 
        initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope]) 
        initial_parameters.append([-y_max,y_min]) 
        initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope])
        initial_parameters.append([y_max,y_min]) 
        initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope])
        initial_parameters.append([y_max,y_min]) 
        initial_parameters.append([-slope,slope])
        initial_parameters.append([y_max,y_min]) 



        result=differential_evolution(sumSquaredError,initial_parameters,seed=3)

        return result.x

geneticParameters = generate_genetic_Parameters() #Generates genetic parameters



fittedParameters, pcov= curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters) #Fits the data 
print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)





model=func(xData,*fittedParameters)

absError = model - yData

SE = np.square(absError) 
MSE = np.mean(SE) 
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) 
Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(yData))


return Rsquared
```

And from here, so far thinking something like this:

```
r2s=[segmentedRegression_two(xData,yData),segmentedRegression_three(xData,yData),segmentedRegression_four(xData,yData)]

best_fit=np.max(r2s)
```

Although I may need to use AIC or something.

Is there some way I can make this more efficient at running?

Comment: Indentations (at least one) are messed up.  I agree that it isn't elegant.  Defining functions within other functions is not common in Python,unless they are small utility ones.  But that by itself shouldn't affect performance.  What you/we need to identify is which task is long, probably because it does something complicated many times.

Comment: This isn't the short debugging kind of problem that SO posters like to solve.  In some ways it may be a better fit with Code Review, especially the organizational part.  But I'm not sure the code is complete enough for that board.  For SO the code and question needs more focus.  For CR it needs to complete and running.

Comment: I see two blocks of code that look similar, with the same `func` definition.  You may need that in your production code, but you don't need that in a SO question.  You probably should focus on defining `func` without the `for x in xVals:` loop.  I'd suggest a new question with [mcve], focusing on that.

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed one of your `func`, and put it in a test script:

```
import numpy as np

def func(xVals,break1,break2,break3,slope1,offset1,slope2,offset2,slope3,offset3,slope4,offset4):
    returnArray=[]
    for x in xVals:
        if x < break1:
            returnArray.append(slope1 * x + offset1)
        elif (np.logical_and(x >= break1,x<break2)):
            returnArray.append(slope2 * x + offset2)
        elif (np.logical_and(x >= break2,x<break3)):
            returnArray.append(slope3 * x + offset3)
        else:
            returnArray.append(slope4 * x + offset4)

    return returnArray

arr = np.linspace(0,20,10000)
breaks = [4, 10, 15]
slopes = [.1, .2, .3, .4]
offsets = [1,2,3,4]
sl_off = np.array([slopes,offsets]).T.ravel().tolist()
print(sl_off)
ret = func(arr, *breaks, *sl_off)
if len(ret)<25:
    print(ret)
```

I then took a first step of 'vectorizing', evaluating the function in blocks of values, rather than element by element.

```
def func1(xVals, breaks, slopes, offsets):
    res = np.zeros(xVals.shape)
    i = 0 
    mask = xVals<breaks[i]
    res[mask] = slopes[i]*xVals[mask]+offsets[i]
    for i in [1,2]:
        mask = np.logical_and(xVals>=breaks[i-1], xVals<breaks[i])
        res[mask] = slopes[i]*xVals[mask]+offsets[i]
    i=3
    mask = xVals>=breaks[i-1]
    res[mask] = slopes[i]*xVals[mask]+offsets[i]
    return res

ret1 = func1(arr, breaks, slopes, offsets)
print(np.allclose(ret, ret1))
```

The `allclose` test prints `True`.  I also `ran` it in `ipython`, and timed the two versions.

```
In [41]: timeit func(arr, *breaks, *sl_off)                                                            
66.2 ms ± 337 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [42]: timeit func1(arr, breaks, slopes, offsets)                                                    
165 µs ± 586 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I also did a `plt.plot(xVals, ret)` to see a simple plot of the function.

I wrote `func1` with an eye toward making it work for all 3 of your cases. It's not there, but shouldn't be hard to change to depend on the length of the input lists (or arrays).

I'm sure more can be done, but this should be start in the right direction.

There is also a `numpy` `piecewise` evaluator:

```
np.piecewise(x, condlist, funclist, *args, **kw)
```

but I it appears that constructing the two input lists will be just as much work.

Comment: I see. How would I use this to minimize an error function? It seems to me that a priori knowledge of the breakpoints seem necessary to make use of this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: My `func1` assumes there are 3 break points, but that can be easily generalized to handle `breaks` of different length.

Comment: I need my program optimally to have no a priori knowledge of the number of breakpoints or to know the number of breakpoints to a degree of uncertainty of +- 1 breakpoint.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how I'd use `differential_evolution` to find the true positions of the breakpoints with this. When I try doing this, I usually get a complaint that `breaks` isn't recognized as an array or that, unless it's explicitly specified with scalar values, it can't execute my cost function (which requires `func1` to properly execute but can't without specifying `breaks` explicitly it appears)

Comment: I chose this representation for `breaks` etc because it was easy to create, and didn't require a different function signature for each of the 2,3,4 cases.  It's a good idea in Python to pass lists, dictionaries or arrays to a function, rather a long list of variables.  But the key thing I wanted to demonstrate is that with `mask` indexing we can speed up the `func` evaluation significantly.  Speed was the big issue, right?

Comment: It was. However, I can't incorporate this into my program because I don't know how to use `func1` instead of `func` and still successfully run `generate_genetic_Parameters()`, and I don't know how much faster this will make `generate_genetic_Parameters()` run, if it will at all, which is causing the actual long run time. It's certainly turning all my breakpoints into a `breaks` vector, which might make the `differential_evolution` take less time (there certainly are less arguments), but I don't know how to set up `generate_genetic_Parameters()` with this as my `func`.